# Make Slider react when User drags it but ignore when it get's moved by the program

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm writing a Music Player in Java using JavaFX. I want the bar ( a Slider ) that shows the progress of the current song to update but it should also allow the user to move the slider to select a position in the Song.

I use this code to update the slider with the current progress.

```
    mediaplayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) -> {
        gui.getElapsedBar().setValue(mediaplayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds() / (mediaplayer.getMedia().getDuration().toSeconds()) * 100);
    });
```

If i would just add a Listener to the Slider and make it use mediaplayer.seek() it would stutter.

Comment: You should be able to avoid stuttering by only calling `seek` if the Slider's [valueChanging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#isValueChanging--) property is false.

Comment: @VGR Unfortunately, that won't work. The problem seems to be that when the slider changes as the player's current time progresses, `seek` gets called (because `valueChanging` is false). The call to `seek` then seems to specify a seek time that is slightly different to the actual current time (either because of rounding errors or because of a slight delay); hence the stuttering.

Comment: @James_D I see.  So, programmatically changing the Slider's value triggers the change listener.  Which makes sense, I suppose.  I wonder if it's possible to set a boolean field, like `inProgrammaticChange`, when responding to a media change, then reset it the next time the Slider's change listener is called.

Comment: I think that would also be a viable solution.